# Name change rate limit can be bypassed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, developer-story, rate-limiting, display-names

Having recently changed my alias, I wasn't allowed to do so again until June 15. By changing my name in the "Display Name" field on my Developer Story, though, I was able to get around this time restriction and change my name today.

I assume that this isn't intended.

Comment: Shhhhhhhh don't ruin it

Comment: This probably isn't an _exploit_ though, in the sense of a security vulnerability.

Comment: Suspension right after this? How curious.

Comment: Unrelated, @yivi. As you can see in the profile, the suspension is for "voting irregularities", not abusing the name change feature.

Comment: Yeah @Cody, was pretty sure it was unrelated. When I first saw this I was even sleepier than I am now and seemed slightly amusing. Now a bit less so.

Comment: yeah, we don't suspend users when they discover bugs.

Comment: @halfer yes it is. It's a means for a user to do something that they aren't supposed to, that there is specific code to prevent against. This is an exploit against a bug in that piece of code. It's low on the scale compared to account hijacking, remote code execution, etc., but it's an exploit.

Comment: @hobbs: we are in disagreement then. No problem!

Comment: Burning the zero day...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But we do suspend bugs when they reach out to users :)

Comment: @iBug Get ready for suspension then, unlucky name choice :P

Comment: They're suspended for real? WTF.

Comment: @GOTO0 Read the rest of the comments. They were not suspended for changing their name, they were suspended for "voting irregularities".

Comment: Now that the Developer Story is being [axed off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293/11407695), I guess this is [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 9):

There are LOTS of ways to get around that rate-limit. It is intended to *encourage* good behavior, not prevent bad behavior... If someone's being a jerk with their display name, or even actively changing it in a way that "breaks the community" somehow... They're gonna get a talking-to from a moderator, regardless of whether or not they stick to the rate-limit.

By the same token... If you decide to play "scanner darkly" and change your display name every few seconds... You're gonna probably get a talking-to from an admin.

Take the rate-limit for what it is: a suggestion that you behave yourself.

Comment: That's a good excuse for dysfunctional coding