# Make it clearer that users cannot change display names more than once a month

Tags: discussion, feature-request, display-names

Stack Overflow has a restriction that a user cannot change their display name more than once a month. While I have no problem with this restriction, I have problem from the fact that this information is not conveyed to the user while the user is changing their name.

Someone who doesn't know this rule (that was me today), would change their username thinking they can always change it back whenever required, only to find out that they have to wait 1 whole month to change it back.

My only request is to please make the user aware of this rule when they are about to change their display name for the first time.

Comment: do you want to change your display name back to serbia99?

Comment: I want to change it to something else. I don't mind having my current display name either for 1 month. But I have made my point clear that my objection is that I should have been made aware of this rule before I changed my display name.

Comment: I should be able to change it for you, this one time only. Tell me what you want

Comment: Thanks @SamuelLiew . But I don't have any problem with my current display name. But anyways, I don't know what the procedure is to vote for implementing a feature but It would help many others in the future if this feature gets implemented.

Comment: @vishal you FR is perfectly fine (clearly written and includes good reasoning why feature would be useful). So that's all you can really do - people will vote on the proposal (so far it is +18/-1)… The only problem with FRs in general is that we have is not much expectations that the company actually notices such requests (nor give guidance on how to actually make FRs anymore) - maybe this one get lucky and it is possibly text-only change.

Comment: If [previous FR](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255369/should-a-warning-be-shown-before-changing-the-profile-display-name?rq=1) on this topic is any indication this proposal will gain a lot of support and not much actual impact :( . Note that linked post has suggestion that does not seem to work anymore so you feel to close as duplicate I recommend using this new FR as target.

Comment: For what it's worth, [there is a workaround](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385465/1233251) to having your display name changed. This is one of the so few cases where remedying it instead of preventing it isn't so bad.